# All curves over an infinite field embed into the projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $k$ be an infinite field. Let $X$ be a separated scheme of finite type over $k$. Assume $X$ have relative dimension $\leq 1$. Does there exist a locally closed immersion $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^3_k$? Is there a published reference containing a complete proof?

I think over finite fields you can have too many points so this can fail.

EDIT: actually, I think if you have a very singular curve the dimension of the tangent space can be problematic. What are the minimal smoothness assumptions on $X$ under which this is true?

Comment: As you point out, this is already false over an algebraically closed field; the condition you need is that the embedding dimension at each point $x$ (that is, the dimension of the Zariski tangent space of $X$ at $x$) is $\leq 3$.

Comment: @abx thank you, that condition is indeed necessary. Is it sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it is, over any infinite field. This is a particular case of an old result of E. Lluis: *Sur l'immersion des variétés algébriques*. Ann. of Math. (2) 62, 120-127 (1955).

Comment: @abx thank you very much. I believe there is a typo in your citation, it should be Ann. of Math. (1)

Comment: @abx is there a reference using schemes language? Unfortunately I do not speak Weil or whatever that reference uses.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: @AsuraPath: it's not important, forget it. Cheers.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Dear Todd Trimble, could you please not these link this discussion to my questions? I am a different person from whomever is the cardinal and I do not see how you linking this here is helpful. Besides, could you please reply to my criticism of your answer there? I think that you reply to the comments of other people (e.g. Yemon Choi) reasonably quickly, yet you ignore my comments for some reason.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I also wondered why you linked that post to this one...

Comment: @AsuraPath: If you used your own name, that would likely prevent these kind of things. I believe that a large part of this community prefers to respond to real people and not to anonymous users hiding behind a "handle". Try it. You will see that there is a lot of good will out there. By using a handle and not letting others know who you really are creates an unequal situation. While I see that you have been very polite in your posts, staying anonymous carries the potential of trolling and you don't want to appear wanting to reserve that possibility for yourself.

Comment: @SándorKovács OK, I will think about your advice.

Comment: @SándorKovács Maybe you didn't follow that link and read through the original post and the answers to it, but I am convinced that Asura Path (and other users in his bounty ring -- see his profile, and its peculiar wording which reflects on my edit to the OP there) were created a few days ago in reaction to some of that discussion, and the account is controlled by the same person or small group behind many or most (all?) of these other accounts. I believe these are things the community should beware of before deciding to interact with this user, although you are free of course to ignore them.

Comment: I am not responding to anybody in particular, but Asura Path is an intelligent, erudite  mathematician, asking good questions. He is quite polite and I think that it is not very useful to investigate whether he writes under a pen name:  so did Lewis Carroll, Orwell, Molière, Voltaire, George Eliot, Mark Twain Maria Callas  and our colleague Lewis Carroll. To sum up: if his questions are good enough for abx they should be good enough for anybody else and this new user should be warmly welcomed without any ifs and buts.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Please excuse my writing again (I deleted my earlier comment), but there is not now and never has been a problem with pen names. But you should be aware that (the now self-deleted) account was operated by a problem user who runs many, many other accounts and who is playing various games with the site. The "politeness" you see is a veneer; I have begun to document problems I'm seeing in this thread: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4251/2926 (so far only a very partial list). Please rest assured that I do not say any of this lightly.